# Read a FASTA file into string JAVA

Tags: java, file, text, input, fasta

I have a FASTA file format which includes like 5M~ chars.
I was wondering if you guys have any code for reading this large info into a string.

Comment: Unless you are working in a constrained environment, just read the whole file into memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code sample from [FASTA_format](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/FASTA_format#Java)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadFastaFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        boolean first = true;

        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("test.fasta"))) {
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = sc.nextLine().trim();
                if (line.charAt(0) == '>') {
                    if (first)
                        first = false;
                    else
                        System.out.println();
                    System.out.printf("%s: ", line.substring(1));
                } else {
                    System.out.print(line);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```